# change pandas column names through static translation table

Tags: python, pandas

I need to change panda's columns name based on the values in a translation table

Translation table

```
Original    | New
something 1 | else 1
something 2 | else 2
something 3 | else 3
something 4 | else 4
```

Original table columns:

```
something 2 | something 4 | something 1 | something 2
```

Desiered

```
else 2 | else 4 | else 1 | else 2
```

Answer (score 0):

IIUC, use [`rename`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rename.html) with a Series:

```
out = df_original.rename(columns=df_translation.set_index('Original')['New'])
```

Or:

```
df_original.columns = df_original.columns.map(df_translation.set_index('Original')['New'])
```